# Google Play tablet optimization

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I published an application on Google Play and now on the page, I see this message :

`This app may not be optimized for your device` and my device is a tablet (Galaxy Tab)

I have this tag in my manifest file:

`<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />`

Here is my gradle information:

`compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }`

I have no idea what else should I do. Furthermore, as I am only a developer and do not have access to Google Play console, is there any way to check this issue before launching to Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

A task that usually costs a lot of work is to make our app to look right in a wide variety of devices.

The official guide on the subject:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes